# One-To-Many navigation property in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many

Does anyone know how to properly implement One-To-Many navigation property using Entity Framework.

Let’s say I have the two following models:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

I want the model to stay as it is – i.e. I do not want to bring in BookId or Book itself into Review class. 
I have two underlying tables:

```
Book:
Id, Title

Review:
Id, Text, Rating, BookId
```

I create some mappings in the code:

```
public class BookConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{
    public BookConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Book");
        HasKey(book => book.Id);
        Property(book => book.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        Property(book => book.Title).HasColumnName("Title").IsRequired();

        HasMany(book => book.Reviews).WithRequired().Map(m => m.MapKey("BookId"));
    }
}


public class ReviewConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Review>
{
    public ReviewConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Review");
        HasKey(review => review.Id);
        Property(review => review.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        Property(review => review.Text).HasColumnName("Text");
    }
}
```

However this doesn’t work when I try to add/remove some reviews to a book:

```
An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

InnerException: A relationship from the 'Book_Reviews' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'Book_Reviews_Target' must also in the 'Deleted' state
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want `BookId` in `Review`?  If you want to do it 'properly' then you may have to do this.

Comment: How are you trying to save the books? Can you show the fialing code?

Comment: If you don't want to add Books to Reviews, then you will need to create a link table between the two.. A link table would hold the primary key of the Book Entity and Primary key of the Review Entity. Not the exact one - Many relationship you are looking for, but using business logic you could work this one out.

Comment: With regards to my above comment, you could name this table BookReviews and in your book entity have a ICollection<BookReview> BookReviews {get;set;} .. navigation in your code would then be then be foreach(var review in book.BookReviews.Review){ ...}